# How to resolve missing requirement [308.0] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.cxf.binding.corba) in FUSE 6.3.0

Tags: apache, maven, osgi, cxf, jbossfuse

I downloaded the Camel CXF example "[camel-example-cxf-osgi](https://github.com/apache/camel/tree/master/examples/camel-example-cxf-osgi)" and I was able to run mvn install command without any issue(According to the [readme.md](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/examples/camel-example-cxf-osgi/README.md) file ), then then when I try to install 
it on the FUSE server(jboss-fuse-6.3.0.redhat-187) I got error message as below.

[image]

JBossFuse:karaf@root> install -s mvn:org.apache.camel/camel-example-cxf-osgi/2.17.0.redhat-630187

Bundle ID: 308

Error executing command: Error installing bundles:
        Unable to start bundle mvn:org.apache.camel/camel-example-cxf-osgi/2.17.0.redhat-630187: Unresolved constraint in bundle org.apache.camel.camel-example-cxf-osgi [308]: Unable to resolve 308.0: missing requirement [308.0] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.cxf.binding.corba)

Does any one en-counted this issue before?(I did not change any thing on this example ) If so can you please share your experience how to solve this issue.

Comment: This is very strange as the camel-example-cxf-osgi does not use corba. Maybe it is a problem with the fuse bundle. Can you try the original example from camel?

Answer (score 1):

Appears to be the way the import packages have been added to the example , remove the org.apache.cxf.binding.corba and install the feature cxf-transports-jms ( this is not used , but i think the examples were following the same convention ) , the deployment should work now after you build it with the changes in the import packages and features installation.